# How can Shor's Algorithm be applied to ECC?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptography, shors-algorithm

I have not found a specific answer to this question on here.

Shor's algorithm can be used to factorize a large (semi)prime $N$ by reducing the task to period-finding of a function $f(x)=x^a$ mod $N$.

This is done by creating an equal superposition over all pairs of $a_i$ and $f(x)=x^{a_i}$ for a random $x$, then measuring $f(x)$ causing the superposition to collapse into all $a_i$ for which $f(x)$ is our measures value. Using "Fourier sampling" (I have not fully understood this part) we can then obtain the period of  $\ f$ and with .5 probability this yields a non-trivial square root of $N$ which leads to a prime factor.

(Plase correct me if my understanding of the above is flawed)

Now how can this algorithm be applied to Elliptic Curve schemes like ECDSA? I struggle to find an explanation for how the discrete log problem for groups over elliptic curves could be solved using Shor's.

EDIT: I would just as well appreciate a reference to other papers except Shor's, that explain the case of Shor's algorithm on DLPs.

Comment: Do you understand how the discrete logarithm problem is solved over $\mathbb Z^*_p$ using Shor's algorithm?

Comment: I read Shor's paper but did not understand the DLP part. From what I learned, if our $\mathbb{Z}_p^\ast$ DLP is find $r$ so that $g^r \equiv x$ mod $p$, we create superpositions over all $\ket{a}$ and $\ket{b}$ and calculate $g^ax^{-b}$ mod $p$. What is this good for to find the order of the group we are looking for?

Comment: You  may find this reference https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0301141 , interesting (found via the always useful quantum algorithm zoo http://math.nist.gov/quantum/zoo/)

Comment: @Frédéric Grosshans thanks for the reference, I read this paper but could you maybe give a few sentences describing what is done, like I did for integer factorization in the initial post? I can read the formulas in the paper, but I'm uncertain what they actually do.

Answer (score 7):

Section 2.2 of the following paper details how to apply Shor's algorithm to ECDLP: https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/598.pdf

[image: Shor's algorithm circuit applied to ECDLP]

The process is similar to DLP, except that we need different circuits to perform our our group operations in elliptic curves (additions and scalar multiplications).