# ed25519 quantum resistant?

Tags: ed25519

Is ed25519 quantum resistant? I am using ed25519 as a cryptographic primitive for decentralized identity platform, thus this very crucial question.

Comment: It isn’t. It is a digital signature over a twisted Eswards curve.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52777/how-can-shors-algorithm-be-applied-to-ecc)?
ed25519 is a form of elliptic curve cryptography which is generally known to be weak against Shor's Algorithm (an algorithm for Quantum Computers)

Comment: That's the 3rd question in quick succession that will probably not be that well received. You need to take some more care before posting, e.g. by looking for dupes and trying to format your question well.

Comment: all the questions I asked are well received which have many comments. would appreciate if you could be kinder in your response, to be aligned to the spirit of such open communities